# Flutter - problemas al llamar variable final tipo string

Tags: flutter, class, dart

deseo poder disponer del valor de una variable que recibo como parámetro desde otra screen a través de la clase e insertar el valor de la variable en los elementos de un array:
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

```
class FotosPage extends StatefulWidget {
    final String id; //Este es el valor que recibo desde screen anterior
    FotosPage(this.id,{Key key}): super(key: key);


    @override
    FotosPageState createState() => FotosPageState();
}

class FotosPageState extends State<FotosPage> {
     CarouselSlider carouselSlider;
     int _current = 0;
     String _num;
     //Aqui trato de usar la variable _num y me arroja error: only static members can be accessed in initializers
     List imgList = [
    'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/read/${_num}/1.jpg',
        'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/read/${_num}/2.jpg',
    'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/read/${_num}/3.jpg',

    ];

    @override
    initState() {
        _num = widget.id; //Paso el valor del parámetro recibido a la variable
        super.initState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es claro, no puedes acceder a valores `initializers` que son los que declaras como variables, usando atributos no estáticos.

Para solucionarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```dart
//declara tu lista vacía
     List imgList = List<String>();


    @override
    initState() {
        final _num = widget.id; //Paso el valor del parámetro recibido a la variable
         //inicializa aquí
        imgList.addAll([
        'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/read/${_num}/1.jpg',
        'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/read/${_num}/2.jpg',
        'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/read/${_num}/3.jpg',]);
        super.initState();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias como siempre diegoveloper